# How to prevent full image from displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Carrierwave for my images. I added a following section to my app, however in the results it is showing the full size image. How can I modify it so that it uses the thumbnail version of the image `:profile`?

show.follow.html.erb:

```
    <%= render @users %>
```

Users controller:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find_by(username: params[:id])
    @similar_users = @user.similar.shuffle.first(8)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render layout: 'new_application' }
    end
  end

  def index
    @user = current_user
    @search = Search.new
    @users = @user.present? ? User.where('id != ?',@user.id) : User.all
    render layout: 'new_application'    
  end

  def follow
    @title = "Following"
    @user = User.find_by(username: params[:id])
    friend = User.find_by(username: params[:id])
    current_user.follow! friend unless current_user.following? friend
    @users = @user.followed_users(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow', layout: 'new_application'  
      end
```

Comment: Are you using [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)?

Comment: Yes, this is with carrier wave. The part that is throwing me off is calling on `@users` which outputs the images. So I don't know which method I should modify so that instead of it outputting the original (large) image that it will use one of my custom versions instead.

Answer (score 0):

To post the profile version of your uploaded image use this in your view code.

```
<%= image_tag @user.image_url(:profile) %>
```

Comment: I understand that part. What I am having difficulty understanding is how to implement that since it's rendering `@users` which is responsible for outputting the image. I have use that similar code in other parts of the app. I'm just baffled at how to get it to work for this part of the app.

Comment: MOst probably the re-sizng of the image might be done using CSS/styling. Check the if any  class is been added to image diplayed

Comment: @SRDP I set the sizes in the image_uploader file. My issue is it's rendering the full image size. How do I alter `    <%= render @users %> ` so that it shows the `:profile` size instead? That's what I'm not understanding.

Comment: I dont think we can do that!,is it done any where else in your project
if so can you share the code spinet.

Comment: What is the class type of @users?(in your view replace `@users` with `@users.class`)

Comment: The class is User, as that's where I created the follow user. It all falls under the follow action. The last two lines under the Follow action (inside users controllers) are responsible for spitting out the users in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the custom thumb size and normal size
as given below

```
profile :resize_to_fit => [800, 800]

version :thumb do 
  profile :resize_to_fill => [200,200]
end
```

You can resize using css to if you want